# How to calculate average EER and ROC?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, roc, bioinformatics

If I test a system on 3 users and I obtain FARs and FRRs for thresholds and an EER for each user, how do I obtain an average EER and plot a ROC?

As I see it, I could average the 3 EERs I have obtained OR I could average the sets of FARS and FRRs and calculate a new EER on those.

Also, when plotting an average ROC curve, would this take the form of averaging the sets of FARS and FRRs, or an alternate method?

Comment: For each user, do you have true/false probability values, or just true/false decisions? And is the system intended to be parametrized individually per user, or should all users have exact same parametrization (e.g. system shared amongst users)?

Comment: @geekoverdose I have probability values. I have an array of FAR and FRR values for each user as the threshold increases and decreases. E.g.: For a threshold of 0.9 I have have FRR of 0.4 and FAR of 0.1.

Comment: @geekoverdose I'm sorry, what do you mean by that? I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: Np! The EERs you have for multiple users will correspond to different thresholds. This is only realistic in case your setup/system is intended to be parameterized individually for each user - because otherwise, the threshold needs to be equal for all users. It's just a question of if what you do is actually realistic for what you want to have in the end. Therefore: should e.g. different threshold for different users be possible?

Comment: @geekoverdose Ah I see - thanks! That's given me something to think about... I don't think it would be an issue in the system design to have a different threshold for different users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case different parametrization per user is conceptually possible with your approach, you could look at a number of metrics (as you already indicated in your question):

- You could calculate the ROC curve per individual user in a 1-vs-all manner. You could visualize those in case you have few users altogether. Further, from the thereby obtained AUC values you could look at the average AUC (e.g. mean, median) and spread of AUC (e.g. sd, mad) over all users. Those indicate how strong your approach overall is (on average), and how likely it is for your approach to work better/worse for individual users - without specifying any thresholds so far.
- the average EER and spread of EER over all users. This indicates what the average EER could be expected to be, and how likely it is to get better/worse results *if thresholds are allowed to be set individually for each user.*
- When only considering *one chosen, final threshold*: you could look at the TPR and TNR (and their counterparts) for all users - specifically at the average (mean/median) and spread (sd/mad) of those. They indicate what the average positive and negative prediction performance is for users, and how likely those can be better/worse - which might be the most important metrics to report in the end.

Comment: You've given me a lot to think about - thank you!